# input() bug on Skulpt?

Tags: python, input, skulpt

Here's the code I'm using on Skulpt:

```
print('Intro text')
user_input = input('Prompt the user: ')
print(user_input)
```

The first thing that happens is an empty dialog box pops up, i.e. without the prompt. Only once something is entered in the dialog box does everything print to the output window:

[Dialog box with empty text output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fpHp.jpg)

Does anyone have any ideas?

(Right now, I'm using a workaround using time.sleep() before each input() -- ugh)

Comment: Hmmm, that's not the behavior I see.  For me the input prompt and "Intro text" are visible in the output window when the box appears.

Comment: Browser issues? I'm using the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: I tried it in Firefox 47.0.1.  But in some sense I think that answers your question: if it's browser-dependent there may be no reliable way to fix it.  Out of curiosity, does `sys.stdout.flush()` work?

Comment: Yep, it works in IE 11.0.33. Must be a Chrome issue then. And nope,     sys.stdout.flush() doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```js
Sk.inputfun = function(args){
    let response = window.prompt(args);
    console.log(response + "\n")
    return outf;
}
```